# Mysql comparing two string with capital and not

Tags: mysql

```
firstname   lastname
John        doe
Doe         Mill
```

how to select * from table where firstname=lastname

what i want is query displaying 0 result because Doe in firstname have D capital letter

Comment: select * from table where UPPER(firstname)=UPPER(lastname). Make your comparison in the same case, let me know if this solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BINARY` for selecting as is data:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY firstname = lastname
```

The BINARY operator casts the string following it to a binary string. This is an easy way to force a comparison to be done byte by byte rather than character by character. BINARY also causes trailing spaces to be significant.

Examples:

- A == A
- AaA == AaA
- A != a
- AaA != AAA

> See: [The BINARY Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-op.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
select firstname,lastname from table where upper(firstname) = upper(lastname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE`, which is case insensitive:

```
select * from table
where firstname like lastname
```

See [live demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/475b9/1).